# Wordpress Widget add fields dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have created a custom widget where I want to add fields dynamically with jQuery. 
It places the field but it just won't add the field.

Hope anyone can help me out to see what's wrong

```
<?php
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_widget');

function custom_widget() {
register_widget( 'custom_widget_info' );
}

class custom_widget_info extends WP_Widget {


function custom_widget_info () {

$this->WP_Widget('custom_widget_info', 'custom_widget', $widget_ops );        }

public function form( $instance ) {

if ( isset( $instance[ 'titel' ]) && isset ($instance[ 'option' ])) {
$titel = $instance[ 'titel' ];
$option = $instance[ 'option' ];
}
else {
$titel = __( '', 'widget_title' );
$option = __( '', 'widget_title' );
} ?>
<p>Titel: <input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'titel' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php     echo esc_attr( $titel );?>" /></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var addDiv = $('#addinput');
var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

$('#addNew').live('click', function() {
$('<p><input type="text" id="p_new" size="40" name="p_new_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="I am New" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
i++;

return false;
});

$('#remNew').live('click', function() {
if( i > 2 ) {
$(this).parents('p').remove();
i--;
}
return false;
});
});

</script>

<div id="addinput">
<p>
<input type="text" id="p_new" size="20" name="p_new" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="addNew">Add</a>
</p>
</div> 
<?php

}

function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {

$instance = $old_instance;

$instance['titel'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['titel'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['titel'] ) : '';

$instance['option'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['option'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['option'] ) : '';

return $instance;

}

function widget($args, $instance) {

extract($args);

echo '<div class="footer_item">';
echo $before_widget; //Widget starts to print information

$titel = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['titel'] );

$option = empty( $instance['option'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['option'];

if ( !empty( $titel ) ) { echo $before_title . $titel . $after_title; };
echo $option;
echo $after_widget; //Widget ends printing information
echo '</div>';

} }
?>
```

I think it might have something to do with the load of the jQuery because it's not loades through the enque scripts, but I have no idea how to fix that. I'll do some google searches on how to fix this.

BTW if there is a debugger for JQuery that would be awesome to. Then I can see where it goes wrong.
I use FireQuery in FireBug but that doesn't tells me where the script goes wrong.

Thnx
M.

-UPDATE-UPDATE-UPDATE-UPDATE-UPDATE-UPDATE-UPDATE-UPDATE-UPDATE-UPDATE-UPDATE-

Sort of fixed it.
I found out that all the elements are being called based on their id.
Since this is WordPress and I'm creating a widget both the original widget and the new instance I create for placing the widget are double now.

Still follow me?
Wordpress shows a library of all the current widgets on the same page as the widgets you use for displaying data.
So if jQuery relies on id's and id's are only allowed once it will never work.
With this in mind I change everything to classes. This works however the jQuery duplicates all the classes and since there are two widgets; everytime I click the add button it copies two instances. :-(

So now I need to figure out how to fix this....

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `live()` has been deprecated since 1.7 and removed in 1.9, use `on()`

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Nice thnx. However didn't work. Do you see anything else. Like you probably imagined: I don't know Jquery that well :-)

Comment: `.size()` is also deprecated. Use `.length`

Comment: Thnx for your answer. I just found a new issue. Please bear with me. I clicked the "+" button a couple of times and nothing happend. Don't ask me why but I clicked the "save" button. When I was questioning myself why I clicked the button I took a look in the database to see what happend. And what do you know! There are multiple empty values stored in an Array: a:3:{i:3;a:2:{s:5:"titel";s:12:"Go";s:6:"option";s:0:"";}i:4;a:2:{s:5:"titel";s:0:"";s:6:"option";s:0:"";}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}. I'm lost